# opencv saving image captured from webcam

Tags: c++, xcode, image, opencv, save

I receive an error "SIGABRT ERROR" when the code is trying to save the image on the HD.

I'm working with a MacBook Pro Mountain Lion on last XCODE and the libraries are well reconfigured.

Someone has a solution or some ideas?

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
// A Simple Camera Capture Framework
int main() {

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
    if ( !capture ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
                     }
    // Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
    cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
    while ( 1 ) {
        // Get one frame
        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if ( !frame ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
            getchar();
            break;
        }
        cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
        // Do not release the frame!

        if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 's' ) {
            CvSize size = cvGetSize(frame);
            IplImage* img= cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
            img = frame;
             cvSaveImage("matteo.jpg",&img);
                                            }
     if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
    }
    // Release the capture device housekeeping
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `IplImage* img= cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);` is pointless since you overwrite the pointer to your new `IplImage` on the next line.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are mixing your pointer syntax. You are creating a new `IplImage` with  `IplImage* img= cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);` but on the following line, you lose this structure as you overwrite the pointer `img` with `frame`.

The code causing your sigabrt is where you're sending a pointer to a pointer in 
`cvSaveImage("matteo.jpg",&img);`. You should not do `&img` as `img` already is a pointer. The following is correct:

```
cvSaveImage("matteo.jpg",img);
```

There is actually no reason for you to create a new `IplImage` unless you want to do some preprocessing before saving it to file.

I modified your `if`-clause to the following which works fine on my computer:

```
if ( cvWaitKey(10) < 0 ) {
    cvSaveImage("matteo.jpg",frame);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent several days searching the internet for the right solution with simple keyboard input. There was always some lag / delay while using `cv::waitKey`.

The solution I have found is with adding `Sleep(5)` just after capturing the frame from webcam.

The below example is a combination of different forum threads.

It works without any lag / delay. Windows OS.

Press "q" to capture and save the frame.

There is a webcam feed always present. You can change the sequence to show the captured frame / image.

PS "tipka" - means "key" on the keyboard.

Regards, Andrej

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> // For Sleep


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int ct = 0; 
char tipka;
char filename[100]; // For filename
int  c = 1; // For filename

int main(int, char**)
{


    Mat frame;
    //--- INITIALIZE VIDEOCAPTURE
    VideoCapture cap;
    // open the default camera using default API
    cap.open(0);
    // OR advance usage: select any API backend
    int deviceID = 0;             // 0 = open default camera   
    int apiID = cv::CAP_ANY;      // 0 = autodetect default API
                                  // open selected camera using selected API
    cap.open(deviceID + apiID);
    // check if we succeeded
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera\n";
        return -1;
    }
    //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
    cout << "Start grabbing" << endl
        << "Press a to terminate" << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        cap.read(frame);

        if (frame.empty()) {
            cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }


        Sleep(5); // Sleep is mandatory - for no leg!



        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        imshow("CAMERA 1", frame);  // Window name


        tipka = cv::waitKey(30);


        if (tipka == 'q') {

            sprintf_s(filename, "C:/Images/Frame_%d.jpg", c); // select your folder - filename is "Frame_n"
            cv::waitKey(10); 

            imshow("CAMERA 1", frame);
            imwrite(filename, frame);
            cout << "Frame_" << c << endl;
            c++;
        }


        if (tipka == 'a') {
            cout << "Terminating..." << endl;
            Sleep(2000);
            break;
        }


    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```